# How to pick an answer out of the box using Selenium Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I want to make selenium select a choise from box

```
<li class="country" data-dial-code="1" data-country-code="us"><div class="flag-box"><div class="iti-flag us"></div></div><span class="country-name">United States</span><span class="dial-code">+ 1</span></li>
```

I want to change the `data-dial-code` can I do this? and thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The click on the element:

```
<li class="country" data-dial-code="1" data-country-code="us">
```

You need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li.country[data-country-code='us'] div.us"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//li[@class='country' and @data-country-code='us'][.//span[text()='United States']]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: thank you....I have a question, can I change the us to a variable?

Comment: yes, of coarse you can.